# Can't just vs. Just can't

Tags: grammaticality, adverb-position

Which one is correct:

He's someone you *just can't* ignore.

He's someone you *can't just* ignore.

I was about to say,

> 'He [the first guy] may be handsome, but he [the second guy] is someone
>   you [can't just *or* just can't] ignore.

Comment: They are both grammatical. They mean different things. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was about to say, 'He (the first guy) may be handsome, but he (the second guy) is someone you (can't just or just can't) ignore.

Comment: Thanks for giving more context. In fact, it's better to edit your post to add information like this; that's more visible than responding in a comment. Users can also edit each other's posts on Stack Exchange, so I added the sentence you gave to your question. I think you still need to give more explanation of what you mean, though. "You can't just ignore him" means "it's not possible to just ignore him." "You just can't ignore him" means "it's just not possible to ignore him."

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77252/you-just-cant-vs-you-cant-just

Answer (score 1):

*Just can't* implies that the speaker is more willing compared to *Can't Just*, which sounds rather sympathetic.

Here's an example:

Say I see a hungry dog on the street.
Saying "I *can't just* ignore him" implies that I would have feelings of guilt if I ignored the dog, even though I may be hesitant to help, whereas "I *just can't* ignore him" implies that not only do I want to help the dog, but I am fascinated by him.

So in your example comparing the two guys, the usage of *can't just* shows that while Guy #1 may be handsome, the person being spoken to has to give Guy #2 a try, which is in contrast to the usage of *just can't*, which evinces the feeling that Guy #2 is very handsome - even more so than Guy #1.